# How to set project back to NOT using SSL with IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have an MVC project which I had set to use ssl during development. I want to undo this. So I updated the project url to `http:localhost:12345`, and changed the settings that says "RequireSSL" to false in the project.

However, when I run the project, iis returns a 302 with the location set for https:localhost which fails. So the project will no longer run.

I have looked through the config file and don't see anything related to SSL which would cause the 302.

I looked at applicationhost.config which configures IIS Express, but I am not familiar with how that is supposed to look.

I have tried restarting IIS Express, and rebooting.

How do get the project to start working again?  It worked fine before originally changing it over to SSL.  And if I set it back to use SSL, then again it works fine.

Greg

Comment: Have you set RequireHttpsAttribute in Global Filters?

Comment: That was it my friend.  I had set that, but then forgot all about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set RequireHttpsAttribute in Global Filters?